# Evaluate image symmetry

Tags: image-processing, matlab, symmetry

I am trying to evaluate the symmetry of an image with Matlab. My approach is far is based on:

- convert image to BW
- get 2D gaussian from the BW pixel cloud
- get center and axis
- rotate to get horizontal and vertical axis
- mirror from center to the right
- compare (left side) with (mirrored right side) using MSE

The results are usually ok but I think that maybe this could be improved for shapes with unusual contours.

Any alternative or suggestion for improvement?

Comment: Could you share an image for reference?

Comment: What is “get 2D Gaussian”? Are you fitting a Gaussian? Applying a Gaussian filter?

Comment: I am working with medical images (usually with symmetry) but they are not always centered. If you consider all the white points (image) as calculate a gaussian (1 cluster) then you can find the horizontal and vertical center.

Answer (score 1):

A practical approach with centering, filtering, derivative, etc. may provide some results. Taking a step back on associated properties, for instance in the Fourier domain, may give you different insights, since symmetry is not well-defined *per se* (local or global, radial or axis, etc.). I am thinking specifically of the phase-based approach in Peter Kovesi, [Symmetry and Asymmetry from Local Phase](https://www.peterkovesi.com/papers/ai97.pdf), 1997:

> Symmetry is an important mechanism by which we identify the structure
>   of objects. Man-made objects, plants and animals are usually highly
>   recognizable from the symmetry, or partial symmetries that they often
>   exhibit. Two difficulties found in most symmetry detection algorithms
>   are firstly, that they usually require objects to be segmented prior
>   to any symmetry analysis, and secondly, that they do not provide any
>   absolute measure of the degree of symmetry at any point in an image.
>   This paper presents a new measure of symmetry that is based on the
>   analysis of local frequency information. It is shown that points of
>   symmetry and asymmetry give rise to easily recognized patterns of
>   local phase. This phase information can be used to construct a
>   contrast invariant measure of symmetry that does not require any prior
>   recognition or segmentation of objects.

Here are examples for testing local symmetry:

[image: https://www.peterkovesi.com/matlabfns/WWWImages/whalesm.jpg] [image: https://www.peterkovesi.com/matlabfns/WWWImages/whalesmsym.jpg]

And some Matlab code, for instance [phasesym.m](https://www.peterkovesi.com/matlabfns/PhaseCongruency/phasesym.m) in [Peter Kovesi Matlab functions](https://www.peterkovesi.com/matlabfns/).

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion could be using image derivative. To get rid of effects of different shading and light, instead of BW, use derivative of the image in step 1.